# Cannot override attributes/implement handlers in Qt QML form implementation

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I'm trying to learn Qt and wrap my head around the [UI forms](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-quick-ui-forms.html). The doc states that I should be able to implement headers in the implementation file. However, I cannot do this (nor override any attributes assigned in the designer).

Here's my BasicWindowForm.ui.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Item {
    id: element
    width: 400
    height: 400
    property alias quitButton: quitButton

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        x: 100
        width: 200
        height: 86
        color: "#ffffff"
        radius: 10
        border.width: 3
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 25
    }

    Row {
        id: row
        y: 222
        height: 100
        layoutDirection: Qt.RightToLeft
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 0
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 0
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 0

        Button {
            id: quitButton
            text: qsTr("Quit")
        }
    }
}

/*##^##
Designer {
    D{i:1;anchors_y:20}D{i:2;anchors_width:200;anchors_x:21}
}
##^##*/
```

Here's how it looks in the design mode:

[image: BasicWindowForm.ui.qml in design mode]

Here's BasicWindow.qml:

import QtQuick 2.4

```
BasicWindowForm {
    quitButton.text: "Lorem"
    quitButton.onClicked: Qt.quit()
}
```

And main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ApplicationWindow {
    id: applicationWindow

    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Play QtQuick")

    BasicWindowForm {
        anchors.fill: parent
        id: winform
    }
}
```

If I move the handler to the main.qml file, it works. But, as it is here, clicking on the button does nothing, and it still reads "quit".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're a little confused with the items name. You should use `BasicWindow` item in the main.qml, not `BasicWindowForm` since you've assigned `onClicked` event only in the first one. Btw I would advice you to expose some event, for example `BasicWindowForm.onExit()` and bind it to the button to encapsulate the item's functional.

Comment: @folibis Thank you very much, it worked! Mind converting your comment into an answer?